# How to convert php hash_hmac to NodeJS

Tags: php, node.js, hmac, cryptojs

I need to convert a php hash_hmac to node.js. I have found similar questions and answers which I have tried, but I am still receiving 
{ data: '', error: 'HMAC not sent', success: false }

```
const params = {
method : "get_issues",
ts : time.toString(),
field_1_name : "id",
field_1_value : 123456,
sort : "status ASC, created DESC"
}
```

php:

```
 $mac = hash_hmac("sha512", mac_build_query($params), $PRIVATE_KEY);
```

node.js:

```
let mac = crypto.createHmac("sha512", mac_build_query(params)).update(PRIVATE_KEY).digest().toString('base64') //('base64') //hex
```

Comment: Where is `mac_build_query` coming from? Best: create a runable minimal example.

Answer (score 0):

IN PHP :

`hash_hmac ( string $algo , string $data , string $key [, bool $raw_output = FALSE ] ) : string`

Example:

```
hash_hmac($algo,$data,$key) // return hex string
```

In Node : `createHmac(algo, key).update(data).digest(encoding)`

example :

```
 crypto.createHmac('sha512', key).update(data).digest('hex')
```

**NOTE: Key and data should be a string.**

if data is object then convert to string:

```
let data_json_string = JSON.stringify(data);
```

Output: [image]